# Page won't display text that was entered on another page

Tags: php, html, forms, session, session-variables

I wrote a code where there are 2 pages. 1 were you insert the text and 1 where the text should be displayed. The first page where text needs to be displayed works but the text that was entered won't display on the 2nd page. How can I fix this?

Page 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";

if (isset($_POST['hint'])) { 
$_SESSION['hint'] = $_POST['hint'];
} 
if (isset($_POST['verwijder']))
{ $_SESSION['hint']="";}


if (isset($_POST['verzenden'])) 
{
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
}

?>


<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hintsysteem</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
<input type="text" name="hint"/>
<input type="submit" name="verzenden" value="verzenden" />
</form>

Wordt nu weergeven: &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['hint'];?>
<p>Er kan maar 1 hint tegelijk op het scherm weergegeven worden. <br>De hints blijven 5 minuten op het scherm staan. <br>Ook kunnen de hints verwijderd worden door het knopje verwijderen te drukken.</p>  
<p>

<form name="verwijder" method="" action="<?php echo $_SESSION['hint']=""; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="verwijder" value="verwijder"/>
</form> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for the 2nd page:

```
<?php
session_start();

header("Refresh: 1");
?>

<html>
<body>
<div>
<?php echo $_SESSION['hint']; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 forms on same page...

Comment: why do you refresh every 1 second? It won't cause anything to get updated, unless maybe you keep re-submitting the 1st form from the 1st page from another tab or something?

Comment: Also `<form name="verwijder" method="" action="<?php echo $_SESSION['hint']=""; ?>">` ?? Are you expecting the value of "hint" to be a URL? It's not clear what your intent was with this code. Did you want it to redirect to the second page? If so the action property should contain the URL of that page.

Comment: I posted an answer to the question asked. @DJones

Comment: basicly text needs to be entered and then submitted by clicking on "verzenden". the 2nd form is to delete the text so It is empty again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line:

```
{ $_SESSION['hint']="";}
```

to this:

```
{ unset($_SESSION['hint']);}
```

and it will work as intended by the OP.

EDIT:

also change

```
<form name="verwijder" method="" action="<?php echo $_SESSION['hint']=""; ?>">
```

to:

```
<form name="verwijder" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Comment: I edited out "Graag gedaan ! :)" https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48173156/3. Keep it in English please.

Comment: Great ! Glad to be of help. If this (or any answer) has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.